# Magento 2: add specific option for widget

Tags: magento2, magento-catalog

I want to add specific widgets in admin panel , but I'd like to duplicate it.

for instance:

> app/code/my/module-links/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
        <system>
            <section id="my_links" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Menus/Links Settings</label>
                <tab>my</tab>
                <resource>My_Links::config</resource>

                <group id="widget" translate="label" sortOrder="300" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Clone Model 2</label>
                    <!--<clone_fields>2</clone_fields>-->
                    <clone_model>My\Links\Model\Widget</clone_model>
                    <field id="status_4" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Fourth Block Status</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
                    </field>
                    <field id="title_4" translate="lable" type="text" sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Title</label>
                    </field>
                    <field id="links_4" translate="label comment" sortOrder="120" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Links</label>
                        <frontend_model>My\Links\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Footer</frontend_model>
                        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
                        <comment><![CDATA[
                        For using Internal Url (Link/url within website) just put keyword after url.<br />
                        For ex.: for putting this url "http://example.com/contacts/" just insert "contacts" keyword<br/>
                        For external Link, Paste the whole link for ex. "https://www.troll.no"]]></comment>
                    </field>
                </group>

            </section>
        </system>
    </config>
```

as we see I am using clone_model to duplicate the same widget. But in admin panel I see only one widget, but I need to see "Add widget" button after adding new widget(for clone).

[image]

Attaching screenshot.

Thanks for any advise and help.